# How to reuse type variables from locales

Tags: isabelle

I want to fix a few functions and constants of arbitrary types in a locale for a bunch of `Foo` definitions.
I then want to fix some additional functions and constants in another locale for a bunch of `Bar` definitions which will want to use the same types as the `Foo` definitions.

```
locale Foo =       fixes theFoo  ::  'foo
locale Bar = Foo + fixes makeBar :: "'foo ⇒ 'bar"

context Bar
begin
definition theBar :: 'bar where "theBar = makeBar theFoo"
(* Here, theFoo is not a 'foo, but rather an 'a *)
end
```

But this does not work, because the `Bar`'s `'foo` is a new free type variables and the `Foo`'s `'foo` gets renamed to `'a`, so now the types don't match.
How can I reuse `'foo` from `Foo` inside `Bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, the free type variables are not matched automatically. From the point of view of compositionality, this actually makes sense.

```
print_locale Bar
(*
locale Bar
  fixes theFoo :: "'a"
    and makeBar :: "'foo ⇒ 'bar"
*)
```

Locales can be understood as structures that are parameterized over the fixed variables. Accordingly, Isabelle has a syntax to provide these parameters, which can also be used to link the type variables explicitly using `for`:

```
locale Bar =
  Foo theFoo
    for theFoo :: 'foo
+
  fixes makeBar :: "'foo ⇒ 'bar"

print_locale Bar
(*
locale Bar
  fixes theFoo :: "'foo"
    and makeBar :: "'foo ⇒ 'bar" 
*)
```

By the way, this feature can also be used to rename parts of the locale (for instance, we could write `Foo theFoo2 for theFoo2 :: 'foo`) or to instantiate some of its parameters with more concrete objects.

In many cases, you don't have to explicitly match the variables: If you have assumptions linking the two fixed names, Isabelle will infer that they need corresponding types. For the minimal example, this looks contrived, I know:

```
locale Bar =
  Foo +
  fixes makeBar :: "'foo ⇒ 'bar"
  assumes "makeBar theFoo = makeBar theFoo"

print_locale Bar
(*
locale Bar
  fixes theFoo :: "'foo"
    and makeBar :: "'foo ⇒ 'bar"
  assumes "Bar theFoo makeBar"
*)
```

Comment: How do I handle the case where I don't know the order of the locale parameters? For example, if `Foo` has `theFoo :: 'foo, theBar :: 'bar, theBaz :: 'baz, theBuzz :: 'buzz` and I want to fix the name `'baz` in the `Bar` locale? Right now I would write `locale Bar = Foo _ _ theBaz for theBaz :: 'baz ...`, but that seems inconvenient.